# How to add an exception of the RestSharp in this method?

Tags: c#, restsharp

Can you help me add Try Catch in this method that return exception of the RestSharp, please?

```
public IRestResponse<CurrentAccountDocument> PostCurrentAccountDocument(CurrentAccountDocument currentAccountDocument)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(url);

        var request = new RestRequest(uri, Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"{Hooks.ResponseGetToken.Data.TokenType} {Hooks.ResponseGetToken.Data.AccessToken}");
        request.AddJsonBody(currentAccountDocument);

        return client.Execute<CurrentAccountDocument>(request);
    }
```

Comment: For context, can you tell us whether you've used `try catch` before in the past?

Comment: I've never used.

Comment: @AdrianoFukuda Take some time and review the following documentation to get a better understanding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Do you want to catch all exceptions or just one from RestSharp? Please elaborate

Comment: @rak007 just one from RestSharp. 
According to documentation of the Page of the Rest Sharp http://restsharp.org/usage/exceptions.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I catch exceptions with RestSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222768/how-can-i-catch-exceptions-with-restsharp)

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't exist to teach you basic programming concepts that you can learn from using a search engine. Once you've learned them, try to apply them, and if you have a problem with the application, post a question.